# ApplicationData using in Console with UWP parameters

Tags: c#, uwp, console-application, desktop-bridge, application-data

I'm trying to follow [UWP with Desktop Extension – Part 2](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-2/) of UWP and WinForms desktop-bridge calling the processes and passing parameters. This example Console [Program.cs](https://github.com/StefanWickDev/UWP-FullTrust/blob/master/UWP_FullTrust_2/Launcher/Program.cs) code includes parameters string:

```
 string parameters = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["parameters"] as string;
```

But the name `ApplicationData` does not exists in the current context, I'm trying to find out, if I've missed some reference or it is different version of C#

I'm not sure even if it is what it requires, but adding of reference `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.windmd` throws another error with `Values`:

> Error CS0012  The type 'IPropertySet' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `ApplicationData` class, please add `Windows.winmd` where in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17134.0\Windows.winmd`. Then add  `Windows.Storage` namespace.

**Detail steps**

Right click project References ->  Add References -> Browse(file type all file)-> select **Windows.winmd**

Comment: Apparently this does not work with .NET 5.0: `error NETSDK1130: Windows.winmd cannot be referenced. Referencing a Windows Metadata component directly when targeting .NET 5 or higher is not supported. For more information, see https://aka.ms/netsdk1130`

Answer (score 6):

@Nico Zhu - MSFT is correct, but I would also suggest alternative approach, which may make your life easier in the long run - the UWP APIs for desktop apps are now also distributed via [NuGet as a package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts) which takes care of referencing the right libraries for you.

It is in preview at the time of writing, so you can install as follows:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts -Version 10.0.18362.2002-preview
```

See the [NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts) for more info.

Comment: Didn't work for me, Windows.Storage namespace was not being resolved after installing that package

Comment: @Martin Zikmund, I currently have this package installed in a winforms app (packaged) but can't access ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values. Is there a capability or a manual Package.appxmanifest edit required? Also need access to LocalFolder.

Comment: @Martin Zikmund, I ended up using try-convert to get it over to .NET 5

Comment: @CarloMendoza please, could you clarify how you did it?