# Windows.ApplicationModel does not exist, why?

Tags: uwp

I met an UWP issue, and asked question as below post:
[How to detect user idle in UWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687035/how-to-detect-user-idle-in-uwp)

Thanks for Nico to answer my question! And he provided an example code here:
https://stefanwick.com/2018/05/15/global-hotkey-registration-in-uwp/
https://github.com/StefanWickDev/ExtensionGallery/tree/master/GlobalHotkey

Some of the codes which report compile errors are:

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.AppService;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Storage;
```

But I cannot run the above code, I mean the GlobalHotkey project. I got 18 compile errors as below picture shown.
[image]

The first error is:

> The type or namespace name 'ApplicationModel' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows'

I cannot find Windows.ApplicationModel by this way:

> Project -> Right Click -> Add -> Reference -> Assemblies -> Search
>   "System.Drawing"

Like this picture shown:
[image]

And I did not change the code at all. I also install the SDK Build 17134, which is required by the original code. Why?

**More:**
To answer Pavel Anikhouski's question, please check below picture. I have the two files, and no items under Universal Windows subtree.
[image]

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski The original code has that line. As I mentioned I did not change the code, and it cannot work in my environment.

Comment: Well, it seems the problem is that you are trying to call UWP APIs from regular desktop application

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I just use my VS2019 to open the project code, which I git clone from GitHub. Then how should I do? Thanks!

Comment: There are two references, `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll` and `Windows.winmd` You can find them in `HotkeyWindow.csproj` You need to ensure that you have them on your machine or update to actual path. You can also examine the `Universal Windows` subtree in reference manager

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Please check my main post, the last part. I add more info related to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Windows.ApplicationModel does not exist, why?

The problem is you have missed `Windows.winmd` reference for Desktop App. You could find it with this path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.xxxxxx.0\Windows.winmd` for more please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56883148/7254781).

If your project has missed **Windows Desktop Extension for UWP** lib, Please install [windows sdk](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and search it in extension list as you mentioned.