# Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.dll cannot be referenced

Tags: c#

In a WPF App I want to use the class CoreApplication. So I need to use Windows.ApplicationModel.Core. But when I try to add a reference to the dll its neither in Assemblies nor in COM. So I browse for the dll. For example, there is one in C:\Windows\System32. But when I try to add it I get the following error:

[image]

What do I need to do to reference this dll. I don't want to use a third party dll.

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59067770/windows-applicationmodel-does-not-exist-why) at all helpful?

Comment: In the past , for one reason or another I had to run visual studio as administrator to perform certain tasks. Since this dll is located in System32, maybe it will also be useful to do so in your case.

Comment: @AntiqTech Unfortunately not. I also tried to copy the file into a dependency folder inside the project. Didn't work either. Also, I downloaded the dll from exefiles.com. And... the error appears as well.

Comment: I see, then only conclusion is this dll is simply not compatible with your framework