# Launching UWP application in simple C# app (WPF/Console)

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I work on .NetFramework WPF app and I need to run some UWP app, like calculator having only APPID (or family package name, I suppose) like:

```
Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
```

Honestly I have no idea how to do it. Google doesn't help.
Process.Start() will not manage, as I don't have exe filepath.
Any suggestions?
I tried to reference UWP launcher but it failed.

Comment: What was the problem with Launcher. I was going to suggest Launcher.LaunchUriAsync.

Comment: 1. It's not available in normal WPF project.
2. I havent' found proper Uri to use

Comment: There's a nuget package.  https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/  Isn't the uri in the manifest? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation

Comment: How can I access this manifest? I don't know target app, it will changes runtime. It may be calculator or something different. User passes AppId and that's all I have.

Answer (score 0):

> Launching UWP application in simple C# app (WPF/Console)

[`WindowsCalculator`](https://github.com/microsoft/calculator) is open source, you could get app's [`protocol`](https://github.com/microsoft/calculator/blob/master/src/Calculator/Package.appxmanifest#L29) name here. So you could use `Launcher` to launch **WindowsCalculator** app from WPF or Console.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var res = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-calculator:"));
}
```

And this is [sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/WpfApp12). Please note, you need add `Windows.winmd` and `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll` for the WPF app. For more please refer this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56883148/7254781).